# Vagrant box not reachable after VPN connection

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vpn

After a VPN connection ( to another location of my office ), my vagrant box is not reachable anymore via browser, even after closing the VPN connection.

VPNClient: CISCO AnyConnect Secure Mobile Client

- tried a `$ vagrant reload` -> (doesn't work)
- No response from browser over hostname nor the IP address, BUT
- **I can ping the BOX IP via Terminal**

**The only way I get it work again is a reboot of my OS.**

My System

```
OS: OS X 10.9.3
Vagrant: 1.6.3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a routing problem. Seems that the VPN client is routing *all* traffic through the tunnel into the remote network. This is a security feature. In most cases you can configure the client in a way that it only routes the traffic to the remote LAN through the tunnel.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem - the only solution I got so far is to:

```
$ sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 down
$ sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 up
```

Comment: Thanks. At least this will restore vagrant connection after disconnecting from VPN. No more restart needed.

Comment: I have the same issue with my VPN, and this solution works perfectly. To make things simpler I've created an alias myself to reset the network for vbox, and bring the homestead up. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Does this work while connected?  I thought it did but now it seems like it doesn't any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace 192.168.59 with your guest network

sudo route -nv add -net 192.168.59 -interface $(VBoxManage showvminfo boot2docker-vm | grep -o -E 'vboxnet\d\d?')

Comment: Sorry that was with VirtualBox on boot2docker in my case. You will need to specify the vboxnet interface for vagrant/virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

Updating from AnyConnect 3.x to 4.1.08005 fixed this problem for me.